# How to make SkeletonFrames avaible in my click event?

Tags: c#, image-processing, kinect, motion-detection

I want my SkeletonFrames avaible in my click event. Is there anyway to make it possible?

I was planning to create a Kinect to place image on skeleton joints. Here's my coding.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SkeletonData data in e.SkeletonFrame.Skeletons)
    {
        foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
        {
            if (joint.Position.W < 0.6f) return;
            switch (joint.ID)
            {
                case JointID.Head:
                    var heanp = getDisplayPosition(joint);

                    Canvas.SetLeft(imgHead, heanp.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(imgHead, heanp.Y);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there's any mistakes, please do correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the SkeletonFrameReady event and save the last captured skeleton to a global variable, which you can access from your button click event.

For example:

```
private Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame != null)
        {
            skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have an array (*skeletons*) of the last SkeletonFrameReady event.

Based on comments made below, you need to upgrade to v1.6 of the SDK and go through the examples provided by Microsoft.  Although they may not do exactly what you are wanting for your immediate project they will teach you the **basic fundamentals** of working with the Microsoft Kinect for Windows, and give you an understanding of how to work with the sensor.

The example you most want to look at, for your immediate situation, is the *SkeletonBasics-WPF* example.  This will show you how to track the skeleton and pull data from it.  It also shows you exactly how draw items onto, and between, the tracked points.

For your situation the most relevant piece is the *DrawBonesAndJoints* function:

```
private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    // Render Torso
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

    // Left Arm
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

    // Right Arm
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

    // Left Leg
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

    // Right Leg
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);
    this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);

    // Render Joints
    foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
    {
        Brush drawBrush = null;

        if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;                    
        }
        else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
        {
            drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;                    
        }

        if (drawBrush != null)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
        }
    }
}
```

Because you don't care about bones, you can remove the function calls that draw them:

```
private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    // Render Joints
    foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
    {
        Brush drawBrush = null;

        if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;                    
        }
        else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
        {
            drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;                    
        }

        if (drawBrush != null)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a program that will draw dots on all the joints.  If all you want are the hands...

```
private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(trackedJointBrush, null, SkeletonPointToScreen(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(trackedJointBrush, null, SkeletonPointToScreen(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
}
```

You'll have two little dots following your hands around now.

Comment: Hi, I using v1.0 is because there's no sample for v1.6 regarding " placing image on skeleton joints and hover button " ...=( I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie... 
Can I know how to save the last captured skeleton to a global variable? Is it write " global xxxxx " ???

I'm not sure about it. T-T sorry but please do help me...

Comment: You need to be using the latest SDK.  If you are so new to this, you are doing yourself a great disservice by learning on something so out of date.  The difference between v1.0 and v1.6 are *not* trivial.  The latest SDK has multiple examples of how to get data from the skeleton and interact with that data.

Comment: I did those some research but unfortunately there's no sample for "placing image on skeleton joints" There's few web site had this project but they din't release out their sources... So I saw http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213034/Kinect-Getting-Started-Become-The-Incredible-Hulk and http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/10/19/remaking-the-xbox-kinect-hub--an-introduction-to-new-user-interfaces   
which leads me to use this SDK1.0 ... :(

Comment: The SkeletonBasics-WPF example in SDK v1.6 does this - and more.  It demonstrates how to draw a *complete* skeleton around the joints and bones of a tracked skeleton.  If all you care about are the hand joints, then you just avoid drawing the other joints.

Comment: ... a whole heap load of updates to the answer based on the comment chain so far.